# How do I share my site so it is available to people looking at my resume, but not on search engines?

Tags: web-hosting, links, github

I need to **show a static web page created from scratch** (HTML5, CSS, Bootstrap 4, Google APIs, pictures) to potential employers.

**I already purchased a domain name** from *Hover.com* and the next step will be to find a web host. I don't want to spread the web page all over the world wide web for now (for I need to add and modify several code before): I just want to provide a link to my web page to potential employers (e.g. by adding it to Linkedin). **It's not necessary to keep my domain name but it would be preferable.**

Therefore I'm looking for a solution to do that.
I know GitHub offers the opportunity to share projects through *GitHub pages* by using public repositories, but me I prefer to **keep my repository private**.

Can you recommend me some other solution to host my web page, with/without my own domain name and without the need to share any repository publicly?

Comment: Would putting a password on the site provide sufficient privacy?

Comment: If you don't link to the page and have a robots.txt set up to deter crawlers, it likely wouldn't end up on search engines or at least well down the list...and how else would it be found?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use any host you like to host your website (siteground, godaddy, bluehost etc.). What you should do to prevent your site appearing in search results and therefore to the world is:

You have two options

1. Put this in each html document head section.

   `<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow">`
2. If you are hosting with Apache (most probably), create an .htaccess file on your site's root and add this directive.

   `Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow"`

Word of caution. When you are ready don't forget to remove said changes, or else your website will not be indexed on the search engines and therefore be invisible to the world through search engines.